# Autocad SCR file to draw polylines - inconsistent results

Tags: autocad

I am using AutoCAD Civil 3D 2018 and have a .scr file that simply draws a few lines (generated from an excel file), however I am finding that the results are not consistent when I drag the .scr onto a drawing. 50% of the time it looks as I expect, and the rest of the time some of the lines are not displaying, or have incorrect end co-ords.

```
-color Green pline 603913.8394,7570974.6134 w 15 15 603950.7455,7570959.1881 
-color Green pline 603950.7455,7570959.1881 w 15 15 603996.8782,7570939.9065 
-color Green pline 603996.8782,7570939.9065 w 15 15 604053.2915,7570916.3279 
-color Red pline 604053.2915,7570916.3279 w 15 15 604127.3464,7570885.3759 
-color Green pline 604127.3464,7570885.3759 w 15 15 604187.2909,7570860.326 
-color Green pline 604187.2909,7570860.326 w 15 15 604240.7861,7570837.9671 
-color Green pline 604240.7861,7570837.9671 w 15 15 604277.6908,7570822.5379 
-color Green pline 604277.6908,7570822.5379 w 15 15 604314.5966,7570807.1127 
-color Green pline 604314.5966,7570807.1127 w 15 15 604388.4088,7570776.2621 
-color Green pline 604388.4088,7570776.2621 w 15 15 604473.0531,7570740.8841 
-color Green pline 604473.0531,7570740.8841 w 15 15 604532.7468,7570715.9345 
-color Green pline 604532.7468,7570715.9345 w 15 15 604582.6623,7570695.0718 
-color Green pline 604582.6623,7570695.0718 w 15 15 604661.0878,7570662.293 
-color Green pline 604661.0878,7570662.293 w 15 15 604737.4495,7570630.3768 
-color Green pline 604737.4495,7570630.3768 w 15 15 604817.9439,7570596.7333 
-color Green pline 604817.9439,7570596.7333 w 15 15 604881.4611,7570570.1856 
-color Green pline 604881.4611,7570570.1856 w 15 15 604934.0745,7570548.1953 
-color Green pline 604934.0745,7570548.1953 w 15 15 605009.7191,7570516.5788 
-color Green pline 605009.7191,7570516.5788 w 15 15 605085.3766,7570484.9569 
-color Green pline 605085.3766,7570484.9569 w 15 15 605166.7307,7570450.9541 
-color Green pline 605166.7307,7570450.9541 w 15 15 605231.2105,7570424.0041 
-color Green pline 605231.2105,7570424.0041 w 15 15 605326.3627,7570384.2342 
-color Green pline 605326.3627,7570384.2342 w 15 15 605435.2625,7570338.7184 
-color Green pline 604227.1343,7570805.3043 w 15 15 604264.039,7570789.8751 
-color Green pline 605217.5588,7570391.3413 w 15 15 605312.711,7570351.5714 
-color Green pline 604213.4829,7570772.6424 w 15 15 604250.3876,7570757.2132 
-color Green pline 605203.9074,7570358.6794 w 15 15 605299.0596,7570318.9095 
-color Green pline 603872.8853,7570876.6277 w 15 15 603909.7914,7570861.2024 
-color Green pline 604199.8319,7570739.9814 w 15 15 604236.7366,7570724.5522 
-color Green pline 605190.2564,7570326.0184 w 15 15 605285.4085,7570286.2485 
-color Green pline 604186.1789,7570707.3157 w 15 15 604223.0852,7570691.8903 
-color Green pline 605176.605,7570293.3565 w 15 15 605271.7571,7570253.5866 
-color Green pline 604172.5291,7570674.6576 w 15 15 604209.4338,7570659.2284 
-color Green pline 604209.4338,7570659.2284 w 15 15 604246.3397,7570643.8032 
-color Green pline 604246.3397,7570643.8032 w 15 15 604320.1519,7570612.9526 
-color Green pline 604320.1519,7570612.9526 w 15 15 604374.6873,7570590.1589 
-color Green pline 604374.6873,7570590.1589 w 15 15 604464.4899,7570552.625 
-color Green pline 604464.4899,7570552.625 w 15 15 604514.4054,7570531.7623 
-color Green pline 604514.4054,7570531.7623 w 15 15 604592.8308,7570498.9835 
-color Green pline 604592.8308,7570498.9835 w 15 15 604669.1925,7570467.0673 
-color Green pline 604669.1925,7570467.0673 w 15 15 604719.8881,7570445.8786 
-color Green pline 604719.8881,7570445.8786 w 15 15 604813.2041,7570406.8761 
-color Green pline 604813.2041,7570406.8761 w 15 15 604865.8176,7570384.8858 
-color Green pline 604865.8176,7570384.8858 w 15 15 604941.4621,7570353.2693 
-color Green pline 604941.4621,7570353.2693 w 15 15 605017.1196,7570321.6475 
-color Green pline 605017.1196,7570321.6475 w 15 15 605068.3974,7570300.2154 
-color Green pline 605068.3974,7570300.2154 w 15 15 605162.9536,7570260.6946 
-color Green pline 605162.9536,7570260.6946 w 15 15 605258.1058,7570220.9247 
-color Green pline 604209.434,7570659.228 w 15 15 604277.691,7570822.538 
-color Green pline 604161.6941,7570651.3272 w 15 15 604199.5231,7570635.5162 
-color Green pline 604941.462,7570353.269 w 15 15 605009.719,7570516.579 
-color Green pline 603784.0512,7571028.8598 w 15 15 603890.9216,7571194.1743 
-color Green pline 603841.2898,7571004.9363 w 15 15 603912.7505,7571117.3467 
-color Green pline 603913.8394,7570974.6134 w 15 15 603920.4434,7571055.513 603886.7386,7571077.4224 
-color Cyan pline 603912.7505,7571117.3467 w 15 15 603998.5629,7571061.5656 
-color Green pline 604250.473,7570960.456 w 15 15 604341.582,7570912.882 604381.387,7570973.875 
-color Red pline 604815.842,7570771.62 w 15 15 604778.78,7570715.084 604860.437,7570661.554 
-color Green pline 604778.78,7570715.084 w 15 15 604737.449,7570630.377 
-color Green pline 605164.047,7570626.375 w 15 15 605126.893,7570569.902 605209.313,7570515.678 605126.893,7570569.902 605090.261,7570496.644 
-color Green pline 605514.134,7570480.162 w 15 15 605476.879,7570423.755 605559.574,7570369.136 605476.879,7570423.755 605440.34,7570350.867 
-color Green pline 604127.346,7570885.376 w 15 15 604169.314,7570950.713 
-color Cyan pline 605681.391,7573276.081 w 15 15 605764.108,7573402.828 
-color Green pline 604881.4611,7570570.1856 w 15 15 604982.8368,7570727.6401 
-color Green pline 604817.9439,7570596.7333 w 15 15 604928.3409,7570763.4931 
-color Green pline 605098.346,7571023.828 w 15 15 605163.984,7571123.319 
-color Green pline 605301.045,7571332.397 w 15 15 605369.575,7571436.936 
-color Green pline 605506.637,7571646.015 w 15 15 605575.168,7571750.554 
-color Green pline 605713.380,7571958.331 w 15 15 605781.409,7572065.184 
-color Green pline 605917.8476,7572273.2909 w 15 15 605978.1289,7572365.2462 
-color Green pline 606123.4142,7572586.8699 w 15 15 606191.945,7572691.4093 
-color Green pline 606329.0066,7572900.4882 w 15 15 606397.5374,7573005.0277 
-color Green pline 606754.5613,7573549.1972 w 15 15 606815.1891,7573642.1293 
-color Green pline 606952.9974,7573852.3472 w 15 15 607021.5283,7573956.8868 
-color Green pline 607158.59,7574165.9659 w 15 15 607227.1209,7574270.5055 
-color Green pline 605231.2105,7570424.0041 w 15 15 605329.3108,7570575.9192 
-color Cyan pline 605583.2721,7570960.4254 w 15 15 605652.2076,7571064.7961 
-color Green pline 605166.7307,7570450.9541 w 15 15 605277.8033,7570618.2776 
-color Green pline 605277.8033,7570618.2776 w 15 15 605376.2123,7570768.0893 
-color Green pline 605376.2123,7570768.0893 w 15 15 605444.9153,7570872.5168 
-color Green pline 605444.9153,7570872.5168 w 15 15 605513.6178,7570976.9436 
-color Green pline 605513.6178,7570976.9436 w 15 15 605582.3199,7571081.3697 
-color Green pline 605582.3199,7571081.3697 w 15 15 605664.5694,7571206.3877 
-color Green pline 605664.5694,7571206.3877 w 15 15 605719.725,7571290.2233 
-color Green pline 605719.725,7571290.2233 w 15 15 605788.428,7571394.6509 
-color Green pline 605788.428,7571394.6509 w 15 15 605857.13,7571499.0769 
-color Green pline 605857.13,7571499.0769 w 15 15 605925.8331,7571603.5045 
-color Green pline 605925.8331,7571603.5045 w 15 15 605993.3653,7571706.1524 
-color Green pline 605993.3653,7571706.1524 w 15 15 606063.2382,7571812.3582 
-color Green pline 606063.2382,7571812.3582 w 15 15 606131.9402,7571916.7841 
-color Green pline 606131.9402,7571916.7841 w 15 15 606200.6433,7572021.2118 
-color Green pline 606200.6433,7572021.2118 w 15 15 606269.3452,7572125.6377 
-color Green pline 606269.3452,7572125.6377 w 15 15 606352.0457,7572251.3412
```

I have attached two images showing the differences that I am seeing, the first image is what I expect, the second image shows how it appears when it is not importing correctly.

I can drag it into an empty drawing, it sometimes it will show correctly. If I then delete the lines and drag the .scr file in again it will always show incorrectly.

At first I though it was because I have a few errant spaces at the end of lines, but it doesn't appear so.

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of what is going on here?

[image: Correct Image]
[image: Incorrect Image]
Many thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When supplying points to a command prompt either through an AutoCAD Script (`.scr`) or AutoLISP program (`.lsp`), the points will be affected by any Object Snap modes active at the time of evaluation.

There are three ways to avoid this:

#### 1. Disable Object Snap

Disable Object Snap entirely prior to running your script (either by toggling <kbd>F3</kbd> [thereby toggling the `16384` bit of the `OSMODE` system variable], or by storing the current value of the `OSMODE` system variable and then setting it to `0`).

#### 2. "_non" Object Snap Modifier

Precede your point input with the Object Snap modifier `_none` or `_non`, instructing AutoCAD to ignore any active Object Snap modes for the next point supplied, e.g.:

```
-color Green pline _non 603913.8394,7570974.6134 w 15 15 _non 603950.7455,7570959.1881
```

#### 3. OSNAPCOORD System Variable

Set the `OSNAPCOORD` system variable to `1`.

This system variable determines whether coordinate input at the command-line will be affected by active Object Snap modes:

```
0   Running object snap settings override keyboard coordinate entry
1   Keyboard entry overrides object snap settings
2   Keyboard entry overrides object snap settings except in scripts
```